# Solve 2D Difference Equations

Tags: equation-solving, difference-equations

If I have a system of difference equations

$$
\begin{cases}
x(n + 1) = x(n) + x(n) y(n) + y(n)^2 \\
y(n + 1) = y(n) - x(n)^2 + y(n)^2
\end{cases},
\text{ with }
\begin{cases}
x(0) = 1\\
y(0) = 2
\end{cases}.
$$

How can I solve it by Mathematica?

I tried this but I do not know if it is correct

```
RSolve[{x[n + 1] == x(n) + x(n) y(n) + y(n)^2,
        y[n + 1] == y(n) - x(n)^2 + y(n)^2},
       {x[n], y[n]}, n
      ]
```

Thank you for help!

Comment: I think you need to use `[]` and not `()`. But when I tried it, it could not solve it. `eq1 = x[n + 1] == x[n] + x[n]*y[n] + y[n]^2;
eq2 = y[n + 1] == y[n] - x[n]^2 + y[n]^2;
ic = {x[0] == 1, y[0] == 2};
RSolve[{eq1, eq2, ic}, {x[n], y[n]}, n]` because it is non-linear, it returned unevaluated.

Comment: Dear Nasser. you are right for linear.. but my broblem with not linear.    Thank you for the reply ... Saud

Answer (score 5):

Mathematica can not solve it since they are non-linear. The correct syntax is

```
eq1 = x[n + 1] == x[n] + x[n]*y[n] + y[n]^2; 
eq2 = y[n + 1] == y[n] - x[n]^2 + y[n]^2; 
ic  = {x[0] == 1, y[0] == 2}; 
sol = RSolve[{eq1, eq2, ic}, {x[n], y[n]}, n]
```

Another possibility is to try `RecurrenceTable`. Which gives you numerical value of `x[n]` and `y[n]` for as `n` increases.   This shows your equations are not stable.

```
tbl = RecurrenceTable[{eq1, eq2, ic}, {x[n], y[n]}, {n, 0, 5}];
```

which gives

```
{{1., 2.}, {7., 5.}, {67., -19.}, {-845., -4147.}, 
 {2.0701*10^7, 1.64794*10^7}, {6.12712*10^14, -1.56959*10^14}}
```

You can see the solutions blow up very quickly. After only 4 iterations.

```
Graphics[Line[tbl], Axes -> True, AxesLabel -> {"x", "y"}, BaseStyle -> 12]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

So you might want to look at how you generated these equations. May be your model is wrong somewhere.